# I can’t understand a crash.

Tags: ios, crash, block, weak

I got a crash from crashlytics. Probably it connected with weakSelf.

```
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
EXC_BREAKPOINT 0x000000000defe

0  libobjc.A.dylib                0x224aea44 _objc_trap()
1  libobjc.A.dylib                0x224aeaa9 _objc_inform + 70
2  libobjc.A.dylib                0x224c8413 weak_register_no_lock + 210
3  libobjc.A.dylib                0x224c8993 objc_initWeak + 130
4  GPS_______appLite              0xd77b1 -[ModuleView observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context:] (ModuleView.m:232)
5  GPS_______appLite              0xd9287 -[ModuleSpeedometerView observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context:] (ModuleSpeedometerView.m:198)
6  Foundation                     0x2349aa91 NSKVONotify + 52
7  Foundation                     0x23479bef NSKeyValueNotifyObserver + 286
8  Foundation                     0x23479847 NSKeyValueDidChange + 346
9  Foundation                     0x23466599 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueObserverNotification) didChangeValueForKey:] + 96
10 GPS_______appLite              0x12c393 -[GPSTracker private_updateCurrentStatisticsWithLocation:] (GPSTracker.mm:1887)
11 GPS_______appLite              0x12c1b9 -[GPSTracker private_addLocationToHistory:] (GPSTracker.mm:1870)
12 GPS_______appLite              0x12c6af -[GPSTracker private_processNewLocation:fromManager:] (GPSTracker.mm:1938)
13 GPS_______appLite              0x12c88b -[GPSTracker locationManager:didUpdateLocations:] (GPSTracker.mm:1953)
14 CoreLocation                   0x28c5c493 (null) + 25830
15 CoreLocation                   0x28c5765b (null) + 5806
16 CoreLocation                   0x28c50725 (null) + 988
17 CoreFoundation                 0x22cd5d91 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 12
18 CoreFoundation                 0x22cd584d __CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 216
19 CoreFoundation                 0x22cd41bf __CFRunLoopRun + 1806
20 CoreFoundation                 0x22c232e9 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 520
21 CoreFoundation                 0x22c230d5 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 108
22 GraphicsServices               0x24213ac9 GSEventRunModal + 160
23 UIKit                          0x272e80b9 UIApplicationMain + 144
24 GPS_______appLite               0x10adc7 main (main.m:15)
25 libdispatch.dylib              0x228cb873 (Missing)
```

and code

```
//ModuleView class
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath
                  ofObject:(id)object
                    change:(NSDictionary *)change
                   context:(void *)context
{
if ([object isKindOfClass:[GPSTracker class]])
 {
    __weak GPSTracker *tracker = (GPSTracker *)object;
    __weak __typeof__(self) weakSelf = self;

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        if ([keyPath isEqualToString:NSStringFromSelector(@selector(trackerMode))])
        {
            [weakSelf trackerStateChanged];
        }
        else if ([keyPath isEqualToString:NSStringFromSelector(@selector(currentStatistics))])
        {
            id oldValue = [change objectForKey:NSKeyValueChangeOldKey];
            if (!oldValue
                || [oldValue isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]])
            {
                // If statistics instance has been initialized
                if (!weakSelf.shouldIgnoreUpdates)
                {
                    [tracker.currentStatistics.time addUniqueObserver:weakSelf
                                                           forKeyPath:NSStringFromSelector(@selector(elapsed))
                                                              options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew];
                }
            }

            [weakSelf trackerUpdate];
        }
    });
 }
else if ([object isKindOfClass:[GPSTrackerTimeStatistics class]])
 {
    __weak __typeof__(self) weakSelf = self;
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [weakSelf timerUpdate];
    });
 }
}
```

Comment: Point out which line of code is line 232 from ModuleView.m.

Comment: rmaddy, __weak __typeof__(self) weakSelf = self;

Comment: I don't know about the crash, but you don't need to use a `__weak Self` here, because you don't have a retain cycle. Your ModuleView doesn't have a strong pointer to the block, so you can safely pass `self` in the block instead of `weakSelf`.

Answer (score 0):

for released version you can see crashes and line of code,

in  xCode : Window-> Organizer-> Crashes

and select app and version from left panels

try "Exception Breakpoint"

Exception Breakpoint automatically add breakpoint to line has cause crash, and you can see the problem

to add Exception Breakpoint:

in xCode :
top menu -> Debug -> Breakpoints -> Create Exception Breakpoint...

and run again